# What is the probability distribution of the density of a random part of vaccuum?

Tags: probability, vacuum

If I understand correctly the vaccuum fluctuates and has a zero point energy. Because of Heisenberg Uncertainty principle the density of a random part of vaccuum cannot be zero.

So imagine if you have a huge part of empty space. And you choose a random volume in that space with volume $V$. Then it has density $\rho \neq 0$. It seems that that density $\rho$ can be seen as a random variable. What kind of probability distribution would it have? My guess would be something like a $\chi^2$ or exponential probability distribution? Or is this not at all the case? What would it's $\mu, \sigma$ be? How would $\sigma$ relate to the size of the volume $V$ chosen?